# How to do a GET request call in Sencha Touch?

Tags: json, extjs

My code is this: I want to pass user name and password to a get request API which will return JSON Output. I am accessing the web services which is hosted in some other domain.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: serviceUrl,
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    },
    success: function(response, opts){
        var output = result.responseText;
        var parsedJSON = Ext.JSON.decode(output)

        if((parsedJSON.errorMessage)== null){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Authenticated');

        }
        else{
            Ext.Msg.alert('Not Authenticated');
        }

    },
    failure: function (result, request) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure'+result.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question here? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I just want to make a get request with params in sencha. And please see my above piece of code which i did for your ref and let me know what mistake i did in that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Right, but what debugging have you done? What happens when you run it? What does the service return?

Comment: I got a error like 'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement' but able to see my JSON data in firefox firebug.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 
{"referenceContexts":[{"id":119,"description":"What type of account is this"}]}

Comment: Then I would suggest you read the documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP 
Follow the link about "more information".

Comment: I ref this only but no breakthrough

Comment: Suggest you read it again then.